# Windows 10 BSOD after last Windows Update - WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bsod, bluescreenview

I am getting very frequent and annoying BSOD error, which stay at 0%. What is causing it seems to be the DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE. The question is how do i fix it?

I tried reinstalling drivers/software and pretty much everything, including the BIOS legacy update. I also reinstalled fresh version of windows 10. I did a rollback on windows update and i am trying with a fully updated system as well. Still I am constantly getting BSOD with WHEA UNCORRECTABLE ERROR.

Also Bluetooth seems to be failing intermittently... It disappears in Device Manager here and there. It usually comes back after a hard reset.

Laptop ASUS Zenbook S UX391

The dump file is here:
https://gofile.io/d/U0SJXy

[BlueScreenView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n79C0.png)

Comment: Try to disconnect every possible device and see if the problem still happens.

Comment: I removed Citrix completely - drivers and software... The issue persists

Answer (score 1):

```
6: kd> !podev ffffc78ffc050830
Device object is for:
  DriverObject f764aaa0
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 1 Type 00000023 AttachedDev ffffc78ffd3144d0 DevFlags 00003040  DO_POWER_PAGABLE
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffc78ffc050ef0:
PowerFlags: 00000000 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=0
Dope: 00000000:
6: kd> !devstack ffffc78ffd3144d0
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffc78ff7b45030  \Driver\IndirectKmdffffc78ff7b45180  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffc78ff7b45000

> ffffc78ffd3144d0  \Driver\WudfRd     ffffc78ffd314620  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffc78ffd3144a0

  ffffc78ffc050830 Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\ctxusbm.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ctxusbm.sys
 \Driver\usbccgp    ffffc78ffc050980  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffc78ff9fd4a20 :
  DeviceInst is "USB\VID_17E9&PID_4302&MI_00\c&2e675140&0&0000"
  ServiceName is "WUDFRd"
```

`USB\VID_17E9&PID_4302` = "DisplayLink Network Adapter NCM". Check for driver update